# Typescript adds a boolean function to typeof object

Tags: typescript

I have a recursive type that lets me deep pick properties from an object, inspired by this article: https://catchts.com/deep-pick

```
type Primitives = string | number | symbol

export type TPermissionQuery<Tree, Cache extends Array<Primitives> = []> = Tree extends Primitives
    ? Cache
    : {
          [Prop in keyof Tree]: [...Cache, Prop] | TPermissionQuery<Tree[Prop], [...Cache, Prop]>
      }[keyof Tree]
```

When defining a function, I noticed something strange:

```
    static hasDefaultPermission(
        client: Client,
        ...tree: TPermissionQuery<typeof PERMISSIONS_TREE>
    )
```

Where PERMISSIONS_TREE is defined as such:

```
PERMISSIONS_TREE = {
        chat: {
            message: true,
        },
    }
```

I get an error: `A rest parameter must be of an array type`.
That's strange. TPermissionQuery provides an array, so why does that happen?
Turns out, that the type starts fine, returning `['chat'] | ['chat', 'message']`. HOWEVER, at the end it adds a `() => boolean` Upon further investigation, I noticed that when you change value from `true` (I'm talking about PERMISSIONS_TREE `message: true`)to something else, eg. an empty object `{}` the type works just fine, there is no `() => boolean` added, only the expected union of arrays.

Why does that happen? Why setting a key value to boolean adds a function in the type, and why does adding an empty object not? I guess it's something wrong with type definition - but why?

Comment: Your primitives type doesn't include booleans.

Comment: Yeah, you don't want to write `{[K in keyof T]: XXX}[keyof T]` when `T` isn't an object type, since it will evaluate to just `T[keyof T]` in those cases.  For `boolean` that looks like `boolean["valueOf"]` which is `() => boolean`.  You're checking `T extends string | number | symbol ? XXX : {[K in keyof T]...} ` instead of `T extends object ? {[K in keyof T]...} : XXX`, so you are missing cases like `boolean`, `undefined`, `bigint`, `null`.

Comment: I would suggest you do [this](https://tsplay.dev/ND25xW) instead, although that's not your question as asked.  Do you want to see the above comment as an answer? (Although maybe @caTS wants to write it up since they identified the issue first)

Comment: Thanks @caTS, I can't believe I missed it.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your clarification of why this occurs. Also, I will use your solution instead as it covers more cases and is simpler. Thanks :)